# Открытие 2-ой вкладки при заходе на сайт

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте, такой вопрос, думаю, многие пользуются Adobe DreamWeaver, и там есть стандартные вставки типа Spy, и вот вставлю Spy панели со вкладками, получаю код

```
<div id="TabbedPanels1" class="TabbedPanels">
  <ul class="TabbedPanelsTabGroup">
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Вкладка 1</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Вкладка 2</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="TabbedPanelsContentGroup">
    <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">Содержимое 1</div>
    <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">Содержимое 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

То есть 2 вкладки и вот как сделать, чтобы, заходя на сайт, вкладка открывалась не первая, а вторая?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте изменить переменную **this.defaultTab**. По умолчанию ей присвоено 0 и открывается первая вкладка, если вам нужна вторая - присвойте ей значение 1.

**Добавлено.**

Думаю, что так:

```
if (условие) {
    this.defaultTab="нужный таб";
    this.showPanel(this.defaultTab);
}
```

Если просто показать таб, то можно обойтись:

```
if (условие) {
    this.showPanel("нужный таб");
}
```

Comment: Дело в том что, по умолчанию должна открываться  первый таб, а если есть одно условие, то должен открываться второй таб.

Comment: А, ну так проверку добавьте (if) и в проверке в зависимости от условия, меняйте активный таб.

Comment: проверку я добавлю,а как менять активный таб)?  
тоесть if ($check == "1"){ меняем на активный таб }  
какой код смены на таб)?

Comment: Думаю, что так:
<pre><code>if (условие) {
 this.defaultTab="нужный таб";
 this.showPanel(this.defaultTab);
}</code></pre>
если просто показать таб, то можно обойтись:
<pre><code>if (условие) {
 this.showPanel("нужный таб");
}</code></pre>

Comment: ии последний вопрос это условие в какой тег заносить? я просто в JS пень. занес в <script></script> ничего не получилось=)

Comment: попробуйте <pre><code><script type="text/javascript">  </script></code></pre>